# Tailwind CSS, CLI implementation: problem in step 4

Tags: tailwind-css

The dist folder is created and the output file is created but contains absolutely nothing...

I have gone through all the questions on stacjoverflow but none of them answer my problem.
Can you please help me?

Comment: Have you checked the path to your components or templates specified in your tailwind.config.js? Is it correct and does it match the real path?

Comment: And how exactly does the build command look you run in the CLI?

Comment: Hello,
Knowing that my file is called index.html here is the code in my tailwind.config.js file: 

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

And here is the build command I wrote in the terminal: 

npx tailwindcss -i ./css/style.css -o ./dist/style.css --watch

Comment: Could you show the content of the file `./css/style.css`?